# Joint probability of $P(X<Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

[image]

My question is why are the bounds of integral from $0$ to $\infty$ and then from $0$ to $y$. I don't understand it.

Comment: The region $x<y$ is in the first quadrant above the line $x=y$. You then integrate across a horizontal line from 0 to $y$ wrt $x$, followed by integrating over all positive y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

$$
\{(x,y)\in [0,\infty )^2:x< y\}=\{(x,y)\in [0,\infty )^2:0\leqslant x< y<\infty \}=\{(x,y)\in [0,\infty )^2:y\in[0,\infty )\text{  and }x\in[0,y)\}
$$

Comment: So we could also say that $y\in(0,x)$ and $x\in(y, \infty)$ ?

Comment: And then we can choose which variable we will look. For example: We could also look at $x\in(0,\infty)$ and $y\in(x, \infty)$. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @VLC yes, exactly, you get it